# How can I insert HTML values in PHP using jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a text area and a button, when the button is clicked it will insert the data from the text area. Only problem is when I am not the one clicking / using it they say it is not working.

The first problem was they have putted some HTML characters that is why it was not inserting in the database.

Is there any way that I can put everything that was entered in the text area into database?

I am using jquery and php and tried htmlentities.

```
extract($_POST);

$message2 = htmlspecialchars($message) ;

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql  = "INSERT INTO sampletable SET `message` = '$message2', `emailtype` = 'Report', `datectd`='$date' ";
```

Comment: Are you doing any sort of _filtering_ on your textarea content before inserting into the table ? Please post the _relevant_ code.

Comment: Where's your code? If you are using PDO, then filtering is not *that* big a deal...

Comment: How are you executing the SQL statement? Are you doing any validation at all?

Comment: extract can be dangerous $$, also you might read up on sanitizing your values to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to totally convert HTML to entities. Use **htmlentities**.

```
htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES);
```

This will convert Quotes in HTML as well.

**Example:**

```
// 1st way : Converting to Entities
$msg = "<b>bold</b>";
$msg = htmlentities($msg, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $msg; // &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;

// 2nd way : Adding Backslashes
$msg = "<a href="something">bold</a>";
/*
Note: we are adding slashes 2 times
because we also want to escape Quotes in Database Query
1st slash is for PHP
2nd slash is for Database
*/
$msg = addslashes(addslashes($msg));
echo $msg; // <a href=\"something\">bold</a>
```

Comment: hi thanks, but can I also ask you if the html values / contents inside my textarea when send from ajax post is still the same when it is accepted by PHP?

Comment: although I have been running some test's and it is though still the same the way I have entered it.. I still have doubts that it might not have all the contents I entered when it is accepted by PHP. I am asking this before I use any htmlentities function.

Comment: There are two ways of storing HTML in Database. 1. Convert it into Entities 2. Escape the Quotes by Backslashes. Wait, let me update my answer.